Конфигурация JS приложения с помощью переменных окружения и Nginx
Контекст проблемы
Есть React приложение, собирается в пайплайне с помощью Vite и пушится в реестр образов, откуда подтягивается Portainer при обновлении портейнеровского стэка.
Необходимо, чтобы можно было из интерфейса портейнера конфигурировать переменные среды так, чтобы они менялись в бандле, который улетает клиенту.
Моё решение (мне не нравится)
Я изобрёл костыльный способ делать это с помощью sub_filter в nginx, который заменяет необходимые строки у файлов, которые он отправляет клиенту. Но в таком случае размер конф. файла nginx разрастается до космических размеров, т.к. на одну переменную среды необходимо писать, как минимум, по две строчки sub_filter, да и к тому же пропадает надёжность - программист может просто забыть, или не так написать строку для замены или строку, на которую, будет заменен текст.
Вопрос
Есть ли более лаконичный способ это делать, не меняя набор инструментов (Vite, Nginx, Portainer), поскольку, знаю, что такая история относительно просто делается через кубер.
